# How to check mistakes, blunders and missed wins on Chess.com?

Tags: online-chess, online

On Chess.com, when you play live chess, when the match is done, on your right hand, above the view analysis button, it says something like this

[image]

How to check my mistake and can I do that without being premium member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on view analysis or computer analysis button

Comment: I did of course, then what? I didn't see any indication telling me what move was a mistake

Comment: @Lynob you need to tell it to run the analysis, it will then go through the game and  mark each move as excellent, good, inaccuracy or blunder. If you don't see this, it might only be available to paying members. I don't remember if I could see it before I payed.

Comment: @terdon ahh I see, I have to click on quick analysis and give the computer two minutes to analyse it, deeper analysis are paid features